# Increase size of root directory / on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

How to increase the size of the root directory / on ubuntu 9.10?.

Please need instructions...

Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders

Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x00065bfb

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *           1         993     7976241   83  Linux

/dev/sda2             994        1044      409657+   5  Extended

/dev/sda5             994        1044      409626   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to repartition your drive to do this - of course, that will only be possible if there's still extra room on said drive.  Please add the output of

```
sudo fdisk -l `mount | grep " / " | cut -f 1 -d" " | sed 's/[0-9]//g'`
```

to your question so we can see if there's room to be had.

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00065bfb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         993     7976241   83  Linux
/dev/sda2             994        1044      409657+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5             994        1044      409626   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Answer (score 0):

You could try [GParted Live](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.6.2-2/).

**Do backup your data before trying**

*Also a [google search](http://google.com/search?q=increase|resize+root+partition) reveals a lot of information on this particular question.*